# What's the ! in the Scanf.Scanning Module?

Tags: ocaml

I was reading through the Scanf.Scanning module and came across this for the open_in documentation:

open_in -> Scanning.open_in fname returns a !Scanning.in_channel...

What's the ! signify in !Scanning.in_channel?

https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Scanf.Scanning.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, the `!` is an ocamldoc artefact that was generated due to a missing reference. It has no meaning and should be ignored.

More precisely, when writing documentation comment for ocamldoc, it is possible to link to a reference using `{!object_name}`. Unfortunately, the scanf module was using `[!object_name]` by mistake in place of `{!object_name}`. In ocamldoc syntax `[code]` is used for code fragment, thus using `[!object_name]` was adding an unintended `!` to the generated html.

For now, you can safely ignore all `!` appearing in the `Scanf` page and these errors has been fixed in the upcoming 4.05 version of the manual (at least most of them, the rest will be fixed for 4.06).

Comment: Thanks for straighting that out

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking, but an OCamldoc reference is written as `{!object_name}`. `[code]` is used to put some code in the comment (exactly as the backticks in markdown). See http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/ocamldoc.html, section 15.2.4 for more information.

Comment: You are right, I was temporarily confused by the confusion in the source code of the scanf module that was erroneously using `[!ref]` in place of `{!ref}`. Thanks for the nitpick!